# Ist das Reflexivpronomen in »sich schwer tun« im Dativ oder im Akkusativ?

Tags: grammatical-case, pronoun, reflexive

> Er tut **sich** schwer.

Dieser Satz ist grammatikalisch eindeutig.

Aber:

> Du tust **dich** schwer. – Ich tue **mich** schwer.

Oder doch lieber:

> Du tust **dir** schwer. – Ich tue **mir** schwer.

Mein Sprachgefühl sagt mir, dass hier ein Reflexivpronomen im Dativ hingehört:

> Wem tue ich schwer? – Mir.

Aber im Alltagsgebrauch (ohne Dialekt!) höre ich beides gleichermaßen.
Stimmt meine Erklärung? Oder ist am Ende beides richtig, und falls ja: Warum?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Der [Atlas Alltagssprache](http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/r8-f4j-k-2/) hat sich mit dieser Fragestellung schon auseinandergesetzt und hat folgende regionale Verteilung von **mir / mich** festgestellt:

[image: sich schwertun: Verteilung Dativ/Akkusativ]

Es fällt auf, dass fast im gesamten Norden die Akkusativ-Variante mit **mich** vorherrscht. Im Süden sieht die Sache schon weniger klar aus. In Teilen der Pfalz, Hessens, Bayerns, Baden-Württembergs und der Schweiz gibt es beide Varianten. Im Großteil Österreichs ist die Dativ-Variante **mir** vorherrschend.
Angesichts dieser Verteilung kann keine der beiden Varianten als gänzlich falsch angesehen werden; bei der Verwendung sollte man sich aber gegebenenfalls den örtlichen Gegebenheiten anpassen.
Der Atlas Alltagssprache kommt zum Fazit:

> Die Aussage des Duden-Zweifelsfälle (2007, 810), dass der Dativ „selten“ sei, trifft auf die Alltagssprache in Österreich und Süddeutschland nicht zu.

Comment: Der Duden hatte immer schon einen zu schwach ausgeprägten Bezug zu dem Deutsch, das außerhalb Deutschlands gesprochen wird. Als er noch ein offiziell verbindliches Nachschlagewerk war (bis 1996) besaß er diese Verbindlichkeit auch nur in Deutschland, nirgendwo sonst. Wir Ösis haben den Duden seit den 1950er-Jahren völlig ignoriert (wir haben seit 1951 stattdessen das ÖWB), daher sind wir dem Duden auch nicht böse, dass er unsere Sprache ignoriert. Man sollte nur nicht dem falschen Glauben anheim fallen, der Duden würde über österreichisches Deutsch ausschließlich zuverlässige Aussagen machen.

Comment: [Deutsches Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/schwertun) schreibt auch: _reflexiv, mit Akkusativ, seltener mit Dativ_

Answer (score 3):

According to Duden (Richtiges und gutes Deutsch, 6. Aufl. Mannheim 2007) *sich* mostly is in accusative case, only rarely it is in dative case:

> Ich habe mich / mir in der Schule nicht schwer getan.*

Comment: Danke. Das kann man akzeptieren, aber so richtig befriedigend ist die Begründung nicht. Ist gerade "sich schwertun" eine Ausnahme?
Der Grammatikabschnitt auf [Duden.de](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/schwertun#Grammatik) macht es sich hier auch sehr leicht, indem das "sich" einfach ignoriert wird.

Answer (score 2):

A reflexive verb usually comes with a dative pronoun when there is an additional direct object:

> sich **etwas** merken
>   sich **etwas** denken
>   sich **Sorgen/Mühe** machen  *(in all of these cases* sich *is dative)*

Now, *sich schwertun* doesn't come with a direct object, but rather with a noun phrase (*damit, mit dem [...]*). And as most other reflexive verbs with an accusative pronoun do, too, one could argue *sich schwertun* is one of them.

Personally I prefer the dative; the accusative sounds a bit confusing, since it could theoretically be interpreted as "Ich mache mich schwer" or the like.

Answer (score 1):

Quite an interesting problem, because I would have been stalwart about rejecting "mir". However, COSMAS II lists about 3/4 for mich and 1/4 for mir; and as it draws heavily from more formal contexts, it would be difficult to just disregard "mir" as wrong.

But looking at the term, I think that it sounds *wrong* when just looking at the parts. I can wash my face, but how can I "do myself difficult"? So I tend to regard it as being idiomatic, and if it's idomatic, grammar doesn't matter as much.

Answer (score 1):

From my own feeling as a native speaker from Berlin the meaning of the phrases is slightly different:

"Du tust dich schwer"
Seems to translate into: "You don't have the skill for doing this easily." 
"You aren't yet finished and might take some additional time" 
The focus is on the effect on the task at hand.

"Du tust dir schwer"
would rather be: "It's stressful for you to do this." 
"After finishing the task you might need a break because the task tired you."
The focus is on the effect on the person.

In most cases I would rather use the first form.

Answer (score 0):

Ich glaube, das ist ein typischer Fall für einen unsicheren Bereich. Die Sprecher verstehen nicht mehr, warum es traditionellerweise  heißt "Ich tue mich schwer" und gebrauchen den nach ihrem Empfinden logischeren Dativ. Hier scheint sich ein Sprachwandel abzuzeichnen. Wenn man den Akkusativ nicht mehr logisch begründen kann und nur noch, wie Duden, die Statistik heranzieht, hat es wenig Sinn, von richtig oder falsch zu sprechen.

Answer (score -1):

I am from Austria and have always used the form "Ich tue mir schwer". This was always considered the educated way of saying it. The question behind it: "WEM tu ich schwer?" Answer is therefore Akkusativ. People in Northern Germany say "mich" but can't explain why. They sometimes say "frug" instead of "fragte" so I'm sceptical.

Comment: Wenn du aus Österreich bist, wird deine Muttersprache sehr wahrscheinlich Deutsch sein. Jedenfalls ist dein Deutsch gut genug, um die in Deutsch geschriebene Frage zu verstehen, und um Erfahrungen mit dem nachgefragten Satz zu haben. Warum beantwortest du in einem Deutsch-Forum eine auf Deutsch gestellte Frage, in der es um einen deutschen Satz geht, in einer Fremdsprache? Bitte lies: http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/a/1050/1487 und http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/a/830/1487

Comment: Übrigens: Wenn du mit »Wem« fragst, fragst du nicht nach dem Akkusativ, sondern nach dem Dativ. Fragewörter für den Akkusativ sind »wen« oder »was«. »Wen sehe ich?« - »Ich sehe dich« = Akkusativ. Aber »Wem glaube ich?« - »Ich glaube dir« = Dativ.

Comment: Obwohl ich mich (als Bayer) schon Jahre in Preußen aufhalte, ist mir ein *frug* noch nicht untergekommen – wiewohl mir Worte wie *stand, ging, hatte, …* des Öfteren auffallen.

Comment: @Jan, *frug* wird nur manchmal scherzhaft benutzt.

Comment: Die einzige Information in dieser Antwort, die nicht auch schon in den Antworten von vor zwei Jahren war, ist, dass Louisa Norddeutschen nicht traut. Auf diese Information hätte ich verzichten können.